# Is selenium testing google maps still supported by google?

Tags: selenium, google-maps

I don't want to selenium test google maps as such, I want to test my node.js app which uses google maps (ie test that the correct markers, overlays and polygons are present).

When I search google there seem to be a lot of hits from about 10 years ago, but no so many in the last few years, which is surprising.

I found a google blog post from 2008 saying they use selenium tests (which suggests that it must be possible to selenium test maps) but if you go to the project wiki they direct you to it says no issues match your search.  I've been unable to find any more up to date information from google regarding testing google maps with selenium.

https://mapsplatform.googleblog.com/2008/08/do-you-speak-selenese-contribute-to-our.html

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=code%2Fp%2Fgmaps-api-issues%2Fwiki%2FSeleniumTests

Is it still possible to test google maps with selenium?  Is this still supported by google?

Comment: As far as I know there are no actively maintained Google Maps Platform Selenium test by Google.